# jQuery issue on click asp.net master pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My Jquery click doesnt seem to function as intended.  The control is being found but the next line of code does seem to execute.  It seems to exit out before it reaches the alert.  I'm using asp.net c# with master page
There are no errors in the debugger in chrome
The customer JS file is loaded on the actual form

webform

```
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
        <script src="Scripts/Site%20JS.js"></script>
    </asp:Content>
...
...

     <asp:Button ID="btn_save" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="108px"
```

JS file

```
  $(document).ready(function () {           
        $("#btn_save").click(function () {
            alert("Test");
            validate(); 
        }
      )    
    });
```

Below is loaded into the head of the master page

```
    <head runat="server">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
            <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
        <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

        <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Content/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Content/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>    
        <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>    
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
```

Comment: your button is named `btn_save` not `btnSave`

Comment: original adjusted that was a typo problem still exists

Comment: Since you are using an asp.net button control jQuery won't find it until you pass the actual ClientID of the button. Use the following in your jQuery: $("#<%=btn_save.ClientID%>").click(...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your code is not actually finding the button. Using a master page causes the rendered html to be different that what you actually code for. If you are using .NET 4.0 or higher you can add `ClientIDMode=Static` to your button so that the rendered ID is the same when it actually gets sent to the client.

Also good to note is that if you jQuery code is in a script file then using
`$("<#%=btn_save.ClientID%>").click()` will not work. Only when you include this code on the actual .aspx page will the client id replace the server tag. Using static for the client id is the easiest/fastest way for jQuery to find your control when in a script file.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's "select where ID ends with" can be used as an alternative to ClientIDMode

```
$("[id$='btn_save']")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the emitted html your button will probably have an id like `cphHead100$btn_save` or something similar. You need to set your [ClientIDMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to static.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_save" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="108px"
    ClientIDMode="static" />
```

This will ensure that the button is rendered with `id="btn_save"`